# INTO CLAUSE IS NOT PERMITTED

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, db2, cobol

I created Dynamic DB2 Stored procedure for select. I'm going to use this generic query to execute multiple select statement, by passing the parameter.

```
SET V_SELECT =                   
  'SELECT ' || SELECT_FIELDS ||  
  ' INTO '  || INTO_FIELDS   ||  
  ' FROM '  || TABLE_NAME    ||  
  ' WHERE ' || WHERE_CLAUSE  ||  
  ' WITH UR';    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT;
```

Below is how my query will look a like.

```
   SELECT B.PROD_TYP  
   INTO HOST_VAR_PROD_TYP
   FROM TABLE_A   A
   INNER JOIN TABLE_B  B
   ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
   WHERE A.PROD_CD = HOST_VAR_PROD_CD;
```

When I run this I'm getting

> "INTO CLAUSE IS NOT PERMITTED".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seems like INTO is not supported for Dynamic SQL

Comment: From the docs, `SELECT INTO` [can be embedded only in an application program. It is an executable statement that cannot be dynamically prepared.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000994.html)

Comment: @EricBrandt, Thanks for the response. Is there a way I can return Selected column value to the calling program.

Comment: There is no such term as `Dynamic Stored procedure` in DB2. You probably created an SQL procedure using dynamic sql statement. What is `HOST_VAR_PROD_CD` and how is its value passed to SP? Is this SP variable / parameter? Is this select statement expected to return not more than 1 row only? What is `HOST_VAR_PROD_TYP`? Is this SP variable / parameter?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, Thanks for checking.Yes,I'm creating a stored procedure using dynamic sql. HOST_VAR_PROD_CD and HOST_VAR_PROD_TYP are defined in stored procedure. I will assign value to HOST_VAR_PROD_CD using COBOL program and pass to stored procedure. `CREATE PROCEDURE T2.SPOF2200                    
   (IN   SELECT_FIELDS             VARCHAR(100), IN   INTO_FIELDS               VARCHAR(100),IN   TABLE_NAME                VARCHAR(200),IN   WHERE_CLAUSE              VARCHAR(200),IN   HOST_VAR_PROD_CD          DEC(3,0), OUT  HOST_VAR_PROD_TYP         CHAR(05))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have DB2 for z/os at hand, but you should do something like this:

```
  DECLARE V_STMT VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE V_NAME VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE V_COLCOUNT INT;

  SET V_NAME = 'SYSTABLES';
  SET V_STMT = 'SET ? = (SELECT COLCOUNT FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE CREATOR = ''SYSIBM'' AND NAME = ?)';
  PREPARE S1 FROM V_STMT;
  EXECUTE S1 INTO V_COLCOUNT USING V_NAME;
```

You need `SET` statement. Construct `V_STMT` value according to your needs. The 1-st `?` denotes the result you get into `V_COLCOUNT` from you `select`. The 2-nd `?` denotes a parameter you pass with the `V_NAME` variable.